# Amazon AWS: Passing append = TRUE to a s3write_using FUN = write_csv

Tags: r, amazon-web-services

I am trying to pass an argument to the `write_csv` function in R but I can't seem to pass it correctly. It does not append the data to the current csv file in the S3 Bucket.

Currently what I have is:

```
  data %>% 
    s3write_using(.,
                  FUN = write_csv,
                  bucket = "myBUCKET",
                  object = "myLocationToSaveCSV.csv",
                  append = TRUE) # Append = TRUE is what I would like to pass to write_csv
```

I am able to write the `data` to the S3 bucket but when I want to append data to the current data it just re-writes the old data and no new data gets appended.

How can I pass extra parameters `...` to the `write_csv(...)` funcition inside the `s3write_using`?

Answer (score 1):

R uses positional arguments in functions (also nonpositional named args- its weird..)

so try to put the additional args directly after FUN  :

```
data %>% 
    s3write_using(.,
                  FUN = write_csv,
                  append = TRUE,
                  bucket = "myBUCKET",
                  object = "myLocationToSaveCSV.csv"
                  )
```

if this doesn't work you can try to use a lambda:

```
data %>% 
    s3write_using(.,
                  FUN = \(x) write_csv(x,append=TRUE),
                  bucket = "myBUCKET",
                  object = "myLocationToSaveCSV.csv")
```